# Unable to open url from nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am not able to open a url **http://192.xxx.xxx.22:9200** from my nodejs application. I am using angularjs for front end and nodejs as backend. If I replace **xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx** with the **localhost** then i am able to see the content of http://192.xxx.xxx.22:9200. Here i am pasting my code.
Here is my **app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

.....

app.post('/home',function(req,res){

});
http.listen(8082,'0.0.0.0',function(){
    console.log('listening on 8082');
})
```

My **home.html** page.

```
 <div ng-controller="Ctrl" class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-3">
             <div class="sidebar">
                      <div ui-view='sideBar'></div>
              </div>
          </div>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
              <div class="first_div">
                      <label>Enter the URL : <input type="text" ng-model="url"/></label><br />
                      <div class='myIframe' >
                              <iframe width="900" height="400" ng-src="{{trustedUrl()}}"></iframe>
                      </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Here is my **angular_code.js**.

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app',['ui.router','ui.bootstrap','ngAnimate'])
         .controller('Ctrl',function($scope,$http,$rootScope,$location,$sce){
 $scope.trustedUrl = function ()
 {
   return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.url);
 };
```

Can any one help me to solve this problem. Do i need to do proxy url?

Comment: Server is listening on port 8082 and you are accessing http://192.xxx.xxx.22:9200. Try http://192.xxx.xxx.22:8082

Comment: Thank you for reply. Node application is running at port 8082, but in the home page i am using iframe, in that i am using this url192.xxx.xxx.22:9200.

Comment: If I use **localhost** , it is working.

Answer (score 0):

In app.js you are specifying port **8082**, but in the url its **9200**. Try correct port  http://192.xxx.xxx.22:8082

Comment: Thank you for reply. Node application is running at port 8082, but in the home page i am using iframe, in that i am using this url192.xxx.xxx.22:9200.